# Ansible - arithmetic operation on variable set with jinja2 filters

Tags: math, filter, ansible, jinja2

I would like to set a variable which would be a fraction of the value extracted with a jinja filter in a role. What I am trying to do looks like :

```
- name: Get size of FS
  set_fact:
    tmp_size_b: "{{ ansible_mounts | selectattr('device', 'match', '^/dev/mapper/root_vg-lv_tmp$') | map(attribute='size_total') | list }}"

- name: Convert unit
  set_fact:
    tmp_size_k: "{{ tmp_size_b / 1024 }}"
```

How can I convert the string extracted with the jinja filter in a number that can be manipulated afterward. I tried adding `| int` after `| list` in the filter but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: can you debug the tmp_size_b?

 - debug: msg="{{ tmp_size_b }}"

Comment: It gives me :
    "msg": [
        2136997888
    ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tmp_size_b` is a list in your example. You try to divide list...

You probably want:

```
- name: Get size of FS
  set_fact:
    tmp_size_b: >
                {{ ansible_mounts
                   | selectattr('device', 'match', '^/dev/mapper/root_vg-lv_tmp$')
                   | map(attribute='size_total')
                   | list 
                   | first }}

- name: Convert unit
  set_fact:
    tmp_size_k: "{{ (tmp_size_b | int) / 1024 }}"
```

You want to use `| int` inside `{{...}}` because you can't have int variable outside of an expression.